# Is there an Android equivalent to Python's executemany()?

Tags: android, python

I prototyped some SQLite database changes in Python and used `executemany()` to quickly mass-update around 24,000 rows:

```
cursor.executemany("UPDATE k_ele SET priority = ?, freq = ? WHERE k_ele.id = ?", valPriorities)
```

When I ported the Python code into my Android app's `SQLiteOpenHelper.OnUpgrade()`, I ended up making a call to db.update every time I needed to update a row:

```
ContentValues updateFields = new ContentValues();

while(keCursor.moveToNext())
{
    updateFields.clear();

    // ...Calculate the values for 'id', 'priority' and 'freq'...

    updateFields.put("priority", priority);
    updateFields.put("freq", freq);

    // Update the database with the calculated information
    db.update("k_ele", updateFields, "id = " + id.toString(), null);
}
```

I've confirmed that my ported code does indeed upgrade the database (`OnUpgrade()` runs in a separate thread so I can display a "Please Wait" DialogFragment on the main thread), but it takes about 30 seconds and I get a lot of the following kinds of console messages while the upgrade script runs:

```
08-27 07:34:30.692  21123-21179/com.appname W/SQLiteConnectionPool: The connection pool for database '/data/data/com.appname/databases/AppDict.db' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 3602 (ModernAsyncTask #5) with flags 0x1 for 30.004002 seconds.
        Connections: 1 active, 0 idle, 0 available.
        Requests in progress:
        executeForChangedRowCount started 65ms ago - running, sql="CREATE INDEX k_ele_freq ON k_ele (freq);"
08-27 07:35:00.612  21123-21175/com.appname W/SQLiteConnectionPool: The connection pool for database '/data/data/com.appname/databases/AppDict.db' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 3598 (ModernAsyncTask #1) with flags 0x1 for 60.003002 seconds.
        Connections: 0 active, 1 idle, 0 available.
08-27 07:35:00.682  21123-21176/com.appname W/SQLiteConnectionPool: The connection pool for database '/data/data/com.appname/databases/AppDict.db' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 3599 (ModernAsyncTask #2) with flags 0x1 for 60.001003 seconds.
        Connections: 1 active, 0 idle, 0 available.
        Requests in progress:
        prepare started 0ms ago - running, sql="UPDATE k_ele SET priority=?,freq=? WHERE id = 30227"
08-27 07:35:00.702  21123-21178/com.appname W/SQLiteConnectionPool: The connection pool for database '/data/data/com.appname/databases/AppDict.db' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 3601 (ModernAsyncTask #4) with flags 0x1 for 60.008003 seconds.
        Connections: 1 active, 0 idle, 0 available.
        Requests in progress:
        prepare started 0ms ago - running, sql="UPDATE k_ele SET priority=?,freq=? WHERE id = 30239"
08-27 07:35:00.702  21123-21179/com.appname W/SQLiteConnectionPool: The connection pool for database '/data/data/com.appname/databases/AppDict.db' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 3602 (ModernAsyncTask #5) with flags 0x1 for 60.009003 seconds.
        Connections: 1 active, 0 idle, 0 available.
        Requests in progress:
        executeForChangedRowCount started 0ms ago - running, sql="UPDATE k_ele SET priority=?,freq=? WHERE id = 30239"
08-27 07:35:30.612  21123-21175/com.appname W/SQLiteConnectionPool: The connection pool for database '/data/data/com.appname/databases/AppDict.db' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 3598 (ModernAsyncTask #1) with flags 0x1 for 90.005005 seconds.
        Connections: 0 active, 1 idle, 0 available.
```

Is there a better way to convert `executemany()`? I'm worried that I'm brute-forcing the solution and that there's a more efficient way to loop through and update a all these tens of thousands of records.

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-sqlite-bulk-insert-update.html

Comment: That worked out well. It feels as though it takes a few seconds longer to run through everything (a difference of maybe ten seconds?), but I'm no longer seeing a bunch of "unable to grant a connection to thread" warnings so I'm satisfied. Thank you!